# <T extends Identifiable<? extends Serializable>>?

Tags: java, generics, serialization

Just want to see if I'm reading this expression correctly:

```
<T extends Identifiable<? extends Serializable>>
```

`T` is a subclass of `Identifiable` and that subclass is serializable?  So in other words the `?` in `<? extends Serializable>>` is effectively a reference to the the `T extends Identifiable` part of the code?

Comment: T extends Identifiable which is a generic class that accepts an "unknown type" (?) that all we can say about it is that it is serializable. The `?` refers to Serializable (an unknown-type that extends serializable). For more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but not quite. The grouping here looks like this:

```
T extends (Identifiable<? extends Serializable>)
```

In other words, this says that T must be a subtype of the `Identifiable` interface, where the generic argument to `Identifiable` must be something that implements `Serializable`. For example, you could have `T` be something that is a subtype of `Identifiable<Integer>`, since `Integer` is serializable, but not a subtype of `Identifiable<Thread>`, since `Thread` is not serializable.

Comment: Awesome - I know I'm not supposed to say thanks - BUT THANKS!!

Comment: I know but sometimes I just feel like writing it out ;)  + Had to wait 10 minutes to click it ....

Comment: Yes, that delay is incredibly annoying.